# Nonstandard use of r functions not listed as methods

Tags: r, oop, methods, documentation, operator-overloading

There are occasions when R functions are used in a nonstandard way in a particular context, where that way is not listed as a method or is listed in an unusual way. For example, the use of `*` in formulae is not multiplication in the usual sense, but methods(`*`) [<- invisible backticks around *] does not show a method. Similarly, in ggplot2, + is used to add an argument, which is certainly not addition in the usual sense. + does have a method, but it is not shown as `+,ggplot_obj-method` or whatever, but rather as `+.gg*`, and if you want to see it, you have to know to snip off the `*`, wrap it in backticks, and precede it by a triple colon, which I find confusing for any number of reasons, among them that this + variant plainly is exported.

getAnywhere(), which I generally regard as a move of desperation, returns nothing even vaguely useful for formula uses of `*`. It also does not find `+` in ggplot2, although it does find `+.gg*`provided you know, or (as I did) guess, that you have to snip the * off the end.

In both of these instances I know what the context is, so I sort-of kind-of know how to mouse around until I find the usage documented in help for the context, not the function. But I find these examples disturbing because if I didn't know the context, but simply found some R code and tried to understand it, I have no idea how I could have used any R help function to learn of the context in question. Both ??`+` and ??`*`return: [Markdown \ escape does not seem to be working for backticks inside of parentheses in code blocks.]

```
Error in if (nchar(Outfile)) Outfile else File :   argument is not interpretable as logical
```

Is there some other help mechanism that would have helped me find these unusual usages if I knew of it?

P.S. stackoverflow really ought to have a [help] tag for help systems, which go beyond mere documentation. I don't have the rep to create a new tag yet, or I would.

Comment: Your question is a bit rambling and unclear. First of all, you can search for documentation with `help("+")`, but that will only find the generic. Then, the `*` in formulas is not a function. Formulas are parsed in a special way and are documented in `help("formula")`. Why Hadley called the class `gg` you'll have to ask him. I also don't know why `+.gg` is marked as non-exported by `methods`. That is an interesting question. `getAnywhere` has a specific purpose, but it is not for finding methods. In general, if you want to look into advanced stuff it is assumed that your knowledge is advanced.

Comment: @Roland Yes, I probably shouldn't have lumped + and * into the same question. If the "formula *" is not a function, is there any way to find out what kind of object it is? The usual slogan is "In R, everything is an object and every action is a function."  Are formula components exception to this rule, in the way that, say, pieces of a vector are not distinct objects? Finally, are you aware of any other classes of R objects that have special internal parsing rules not documented as methods?

Comment: The `*` in a formula object is a symbol: `f <- ~ x * y; str(f[[2]][[1]])`. If you evaluate that symbol in the global environment (or anywhere where the function is on the search path), you'd get indeed the multiplication function: `eval(f[[2]][[1]])`. However, functions that handle formulas (such as `terms.formula`) don't evaluate the symbol in the global environment (and thus don't find the function bound to it). Formulas are handled by dedicated [C code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/src/model.c#L1650).

Comment: Have you studied the [language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html)? If you want to understand the inner workings of R you need to study that document and R's source code. I'm by no means an expert regarding the latter (as my knowledge of C is extremely limited).

Answer (score 1):

`methods()` mentions in its documentation that you can both provide the generic function (e.g. `+` in your case) or the function name as a string. `methods("+")` seems to give the right result for me.

```
> methods("+")   
[1] +.Date   +.POSIXt
> library(ggplot2)
> methods('+')
[1] +.Date   +.gg*    +.POSIXt
```

You can find more info on general S3 terminology and procedures [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html)

When you load `ggplot2`, you can see references to `+.gg*`. This means that the `+` function is overloaded for objects of the class `gg`. The asterisk is there to highlight that the function is non-visible. However, when you check the class of a ggplot object, you can see that it indeed is an element of the class 'gg'.

```
> p <- ggplot(data.frame())
> class(p)
[1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

Since `+.gg` is non-visible (hence the asterisk), I can indeed use `getAnywhere()` to see the source.

```
> getAnywhere('+.gg')
A single object matching ‘+.gg’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for + from namespace ggplot2
  namespace:ggplot2
with value

function (e1, e2) 
{
    e2name <- deparse(substitute(e2))
    if (is.theme(e1)) 
        add_theme(e1, e2, e2name)
    else if (is.ggplot(e1)) 
        add_ggplot(e1, e2, e2name)
}
<environment: namespace:ggplot2>
```

Comment: Two questions: 1. When you say that after loading "you can see references to +.GG", are you referring to :::, or something more? I don't see function help for it. 2. Is the asterisk convention idiosyncratic, or R-wide?  If the latter, might you know where it is documented?

Comment: @andrewH I mean after loading ggplot2, you can see the +.gg function via methods. The ::: also works of course via ``ggplot2:::`+.gg` ``. I don't think that the asterisk notation is R-wide. At least I haven't seen it anywhere else.

Comment: @andrewH It is also strange that `methods("+")` returns `+.gg*` while `methods(class = "ggplot2")` returns `+` (no asterisk). This has probably something to do with the internal priority of R. R will first check if the base + function can handle it. If the class is something unknown to him, he will redirect it to the right add operation.